# SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation error

Tags: php, laravel

Can't figure out why I am getting this error? I am using posgres I feel like I am missing some important link to figure this whole thing out ?
Basically I need to link the comment to the blog post with the id

> SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR: invalid input
>   syntax for integer: "{blog}" (SQL: select * from "blogs" where "id" =
>   {blog} limit 1)

**Comments controller**

```
use App\Blog;
use App\Comment;

class CommentsController extends Controller
{
    // add store method
    public function store(Blog $blog)
    {
        Comment::create([
            'body'=> request('body'),
            'blog_id' => $blog->id
        ]);

        return back();
    }
}
```

**web.php**

```
Route::post('blog/{blog}/comments', 'CommentsController@store');
```

form head with request:

```
<form method="POST" action="/blog/{blog}/comments">
```

Comment: sounds like `{blog}` isn't being turned into an integer? Can you check?

Comment: <form method="POST" action="/blog/{(int)blog}/comments"> this way you mean ?

Answer (score 3):

As you have it now, `action="/blog/{blog}/comments">` will return just `/blog/{blog}/comments` as action, since `{blog}` is not parsed by Blade.

Give your route a name:

```
Route::post('blog/{blog}/comments', 'CommentsController@store')->name('blogcomments');
```

In your `<form>` set the action to the named route (blogcomments), giving it the current `$blog` as parameter:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('blogcomments', ['blog' => $blog] }}">
```

Read more on named routes and parameters at https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#named-routes

Not tested! ;)